# Are flags being looked at?

Tags: support, moderation, flags

I was wondering if flags are being looked at these days?

I see a number of flags that I have made that have had no action on them since 17 May 2013.

Comment: Have you had a look at the "helpful flags" link in your profile?

Answer (score 8):

Our current average flag handling time over the last month is about 3.5 hours, mostly because the mods all live in nearly the same time zone and tend to be asleep at the same time. During the day I get flags on my watch, so they're generally handled pretty fast:

[Picture of a flag on my watch http://so.mrozekma.com/pebble-flag.jpg](http://so.mrozekma.com/pebble-flag.jpg)

---

In your specific case, I do see a bunch of unprocessed flags on your account if I go looking for them. We can't see flag weight anymore, but based on the large number of declined flags you've had in the past (they actually outnumber the helpful flags), your flag weight has probably reached 0, which means [your flags are no longer reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82445/what-happens-when-you-reach-zero-flag-weight)

Unfortunately at the moment this is permanent; we'll never see your flags, and we can't modify your flag weight directly, so it will be stuck at 0. They're looking into [redesigning this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405), but for the moment I think the only thing you can do is [contact Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact)

Comment: *Sooo* tempted to start a flagging frenzy now that I know you get zapped for each one... :)

Answer (score 2):

There are currently zero open moderator flags on this site. Flags are almost always dealt with in a matter of hours.

Comment: There are still my flags that have not been addressed and are languishing.  Thus there are NOT ZERO open moderator flags.